# Subqueries to SELECT multiple COUNTs from two tables in one query

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with what appears to be the most complicated SQL query I've ever written!

**Database structure**:

```
frog_shared.staff
`ID`, `Firstname`, `Surname`

frog_observations.observations
`ID`, `Teacher_ID`, `Type`, `Main_Positive_Aspect`, `Main_Development_Aspect`, `Grade_for_Behaviour`, `Grade_for_Attainment`, `Grade_for_Teaching`

frog_observations.aspects
`ID`, `Observation_ID`, `Label_ID`, `Type`

frog_observations.aspect_labels
`ID`, `Title`
```

**Sample data**:

```
Member of staff:
`12345`, `Duncan`, `Wraight`

Observation:
`9888`, `12345`, `Formal`, `5`, `7`, `1`, `1`, `1`

Aspects:
`101`, `9888`, `2`, `P`

Aspect labels:
`2`, `Questioning`
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**:

I'd like to produce a list of our best teachers in a specific observation aspect. For example, I'd like to see my top 5 teachers for "Questioning".

On top of that, I'd like to filter the data somewhat:

- Aspects from both formal (`Type=Formal`) and sharing best practice (`Type=SBP`) observations should be counted
- Aspects from formal observations should only be counted if that observation's grades are at most 2 across the board (no higher, i.e. can't have two grades at 2 and one at 3)  but sharing best practice observations all have 0 for the grades
- The main positive aspect, recorded in the observations table, should be weighted in the count
- For formal observations, the main positive aspect should be weighted at 3* the amount of a normal aspect
- For sharing best practice observations, the main positive aspect should be weighted at 2* the amount of a normal aspect

**My attempts**:

This statement filters the observations by their grades, but doesn't include any main positive aspects (they weren't included in the original system)

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Teacher`,
  COUNT( * ) AS Total,
  GREATEST(o.`Achievement_Grade`, o.`Behaviour_Grade`, o.`Teaching_Grade`) AS `Worst Grade`
FROM frog_observations.observations o
  INNER JOIN frog_shared.staff s ON o.Teacher_ID = s.ID
  INNER JOIN frog_observations.aspects a ON o.ID = a.Observation_ID
WHERE a.Aspect_ID =  4
  AND ( GREATEST(o.`Achievement_Grade`, o.`Behaviour_Grade`, o.`Teaching_Grade`) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 ) AND o.Datetime > '2011-09-01'
  AND a.Type =  'P'
GROUP BY s.ID
ORDER BY `Total` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Now the way I'd like to do it is something like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Teacher`,
  COUNT(mp.*) AS `Number of Appraisal Main Positives`,
  COUNT(sp.*) AS `Number of SBP Main Positives`,
  COUNT(a.*) AS `Number of Other Positives`,
  SUM(`Number of Appraisal Main Positives` + `Number of SBP Main Positives` `Number of Other Positives`) AS `Total`
FROM
  `frog_observations`.`observations` o,
  ( `frog_observations`.`observations` WHERE `Type` = 'Formal') AS mp,
  ( `frog_observations`.`observations` WHERE `Type` = 'SBP') AS sp
INNER JOIN
  `frog_observations`.`aspects` a ON a.Observation_ID = o.ID
GROUP BY s.ID
```

Unfortunately, other than knowing the headings I want (i.e. `number of appraisal main positives`, `number of sharing best practice positives`, `number of standard positives` and a `weighted total`), I have no idea how to write what I presume will be subqueries to get all of this information from a single statement.

Any guidance appreciated.

---

## Edit: Sample input/output

**Input**
User wants to view Top 5 members of staff for the aspect `Questioning`

**Process**
 - Aspect `Questioning` has ID `4` in the `aspect_labels` table.
 - System should then, for each member of staff, count the `observations` they have with `Main_Positive_Aspect` set to `4`. Some of these observations will be of `Type` Formal and some will be of `Type` SBP.
 - System should also then count the number of rows in the `aspects` table for each member of staff where the `Aspect_ID` is `4`.

**Output**

Key:

- *FMP* = Number of rows in the `observations` table where `Type` is Formal; `GREATEST(Achievement_Grade, Behaviour_Grade, Teaching_Grade) BETWEEN 1 AND 2`;  and the `Main_Positive_Aspect` is `4` (i.e. `Questioning` in the `aspects_label` table)
- *SMP* = Number of rows in the `observations` table where `Type` is SBP and the `Main_Positive_Aspect` is `4`
- *Other* = Number of rows in the `aspects` table where `Aspect_ID` is `4` for each member of staff (via the `o.Observation_ID` -> `o.Staff_ID` link)
- *Points* = Weighted total for each of these - each FMP is worth 3 points, each SMP is worth 2 points and each Other is worth 1. Query should then be ordered, `DESC`, by this column.

Example output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|       Staff Name      FMP     SMP     Other       Points  |
|------------------------------------------------------------
|       D Wraight       2       1       4           12      |
|       A Nother        3       0       0           9       |
|       J Bloggs        0       4       1           9       |
|       J Arthur        1       1       1           6       |
|       M Turner        0       1       0           2       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Here are the queries, written individually, which work on my database. Basically I need to amalgamate these into one query. If that's possible!

```
#=======#
#  FMP  #
#=======#

SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Teacher`,
  COUNT( * ) AS `FMP`
FROM frog_observations.observations o
  INNER JOIN frog_shared.staff s ON o.Teacher_ID = s.ID
WHERE o.Main_Positive  =  4
  AND o.Type = 'F'
  AND ( GREATEST(o.`Achievement_Grade`, o.`Behaviour_Grade`, o.`Teaching_Grade`) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 )
GROUP BY s.ID

#=======#
#  SMP  #
#=======#

SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Teacher`,
  COUNT( * ) AS `SMP`
FROM frog_observations.observations o
  INNER JOIN frog_shared.staff s ON o.Teacher_ID = s.ID
WHERE o.Main_Positive  =  4
  AND o.Type = 'S'
GROUP BY s.ID

#=========#
#  Other  #
#=========#

SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Teacher`,
  COUNT( * ) AS `Other`
FROM observations o
  INNER JOIN frog_shared.staff s ON o.Teacher_ID = s.ID
  INNER JOIN aspects a ON o.ID = a.Observation_ID
WHERE a.Aspect_ID = 4
  AND a.Type = 'P'
GROUP BY s.ID
```

Comment: . . Please provide some sample inputs and expected results.  The rules are quite difficult to follow.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I've added some input and output processes - I think!

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for the initial cut...

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS Teacher,
  sum(Case when `Type` = 'Formal' then 1 else 0 end) AS `Number of Appraisal Main Positives`,
  sum(Case when `Type` = 'SBP' then 1 else 0 end)  AS `Number of SBP Main Positives`,
  coalesce(OtherPositives,0) AS `Number of Other Positives`,
  sum(Case when `Type` in ( 'Formal' ,'SBP') then 1 else 0 end) + coalesce(OtherPositives,0)  AS `Total`
FROM observations o
INNER JOIN staff s ON o.Teacher_ID = s.ID
LEFT JOIN (select Observation_ID, count(*) as OtherPositives) from aspects where Label_ID=4 group by Observation_ID) a ON a.Observation_ID = o.ID
WHERE Main_Positive =4
GROUP BY s.ID
```

Comment: Almost Steph, but the `other positives` are all stored in a separate table - `aspects` so I need to count occurrences of those for that value.

Comment: Will there only be an aspect if it is positive and only one aspect per observation?

Comment: Yeah - positive aspects only (I'll be making a similar but separate query for developmental aspects). There can be any number of aspects per observation but never more than one of each type, i.e. an `observation` may have one `Questioning` aspect (ID 4), one `Student engagement` (ID 5), one `Student enthusiasm` (ID 6) etc but never two of any.

Comment: Hi Steph. I've now got a list of all staff members, with the number of aspects they've received in each column. That's a good start, but I need it to be specific to one aspect - i.e. where `Main_Positive_Aspect` is `4` (the `Aspect_ID` for `Questioning) and where the entries in the `aspects` table also have `Aspect_ID` of 4. Does that make sense? My original post, at the bottom, may provide some clarity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've constrained using Main_Positive =4 for the outside query and Label_ID=4 in the sub-query which seems to be what you're after *I think*. The weighting is just adding multipliers into the total column.

Comment: Steph - thanks again. That's working for the `Main_Positive` now, but not the `Others`. Is it because the `WHERE Main_Positive = 4` is constraining the list of aspects to only include those where the associated observation has a Main_Positive of 4 too?

Comment: Nope this bad boy is...  `where Label_ID=4` - you can remove it if you want all aspects to be taken into account

Comment: Sorry Steph, my bad - haven't really explained that well. At the moment, the output from your query is displaying `0` for `Others`, even when relevant aspects (i.e. aspects with ID 4) should be displaying. Teachers may have observations where their main positive aspect is ID 5 but they still have a separate aspect of 4. It's those latter aspects that I want to count in the Others column.

Comment: I'm getting quite confused now, but there are two levers i.e. the two WHEREs, that you can pull to change what's happening.  The `where main_positive` determines which observations are included and the `where label_id` determines which aspects are included.  Modify them as appropriate to filter the values down to what you're after.

Comment: Ahh, yes, there's the problem I think - there will be some (quite a few) observations where the `Main_Positive_Aspect` is NOT 4, but the associated aspects IS equal to 4.